# Produce PostScript file in TeXShop on MacOS X

Tags: texshop

I would like to produce a PostScript file when compiling my LaTeX file on TeXShop running on MacOS X. I already tried checking the box "Save Postscript File" under the preferences->Engine tab + selected the radio button "Tex + DVI" in the Typesetting tab, but this doesn't produce the .ps file.

Any suggestion? This is driving me crazy.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With TeXShop go to typeset and enable LaTeX, dvi and ghostscript. To set this as default go to TeXShop - Preferences - Typesetting. It creates the ps and pdf file

Comment: Under "typeset" I only have Typeset, PlainTeX, LaTeX, BibTeX, MakeIndex, MetaPost, ConTeXt, and then PdfTex, TeX and DVI, Personal Script. Perhaps TeX and DVI? I tried this one and gives me errors about one image and its size.

Comment: choose LaTeX. But take care that you use only eps Images, if you have one. LaTeX can handle only ps and eps images.

Comment: By choosing LaTeX the compiling procedure starts, no errors shown, pdf compiled as it is supposed to be but no .ps file is produced.

Comment: did you enabled  dvips and ghostscript?

Comment: No sorry, I can't find under the Typesetting tab in the preferences where I can enable "LaTeX. dvi and ghostscript". Maybe version issue? Mine is 3.11.

Comment: I have no Mac here to say more

Comment: For future reference, under the "typeset" tab in TeXShop window, select "TeX and DVI" and it should produce it.

Comment: On top of Herbert's answer, if you want the Postscript file, make sure that you check the "Save Postscript File" box at TeXShop >> Preferences >> Engine. For me, the box is unchecked as default.