# How do I check the plagiarism on Turnitin of Latex generated thesis/dissertation PDF (Thesis size: 240 pages and 5.21 MB)?

Tags: pdftex, pdf

I have written my thesis in latex and this thesis contains 240 pages. The size of this thesis is 5.21 MB. However, I am unable to check this pdf on Turnitin. Turnitin is not yielding any specific error but simply does not process this file after submission.

Can you please tell me how can I make this Latex generated pdf compatible for Turnitin plagiarism checker?

Comment: No idea about Turnitin, but if it's a file size issue and you are only interested in a textual comparison, you can probably pass the `[draft]`option to whichever package you use for images, see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49277/what-does-the-draft-mode-change

Comment: File size should not be an issue because I have checked a larger size file than this on Turnitin. Even, Turnitin has also mentioned that it can check up to 40 MB file.

Comment: Okay. https://help.turnitin.com/feedback-studio/turnitin-website/student/submitting-a-paper/file-requirements.htm says "Turnitin will not accept PDF image files, forms, or portfolios, files that do not contain highlightable text (e.g. a scanned file - usually an image), documents containing multiple files or files created with software other than Adobe Acrobat®." I suspect that means PDF/A, so I suggest you research how to transform your document to a PDF/A format (I am, however, not sure enough to give this as an answer.)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am also looking for that option but unable to find. Turnitin mentions that they do not support pdflatex.

Comment: I've had students produce PDF from TeX and upload successfully to Turnitin, even though submission is set to only accept files it can process. Has something changed?

Comment: Also, I regularly have students upload PDFs produced using other word processors on Macs, as opposed to Adobe Acrobat. All of these get originality reports. I suspect this is more of a "if it isn't Adobe Acrobat and it doesn't work, it isn't our problem" than a genuine "Adobe Acrobat only". Ridiculous rule anyway. Could you convert your file to `.ps`?

Comment: I also used to check the journal or conference papers or small reports, which were written in Latex. Although, Turnitin mentioned that it does not support pdflatex, but I never got any issue. However, when I tried to check thesis then I encountered this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to follow the instructions in this related question:
[Produce PostScript file in TeXShop on MacOS X](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104363/produce-postscript-file-in-texshop-on-macos-x)

The question is specific to TexShop on macOS, but the idea of first generating the .ps file then converting to .pdf using Adobe Distiller applies more generally.

https://helpx.adobe.com/au/acrobat/using/creating-pdfs-acrobat-distiller.html

If you don't have Distiller, you could also try Ghostscript
http://slantchev.ucsd.edu/edu/latex/latex-pdf.html

TurnItIn isn't the only software that struggles with PDF files generated from pdflatex, but it does seem to be the most fussy.